# Eclipse Source Code Error

Tags: java, eclipse, error-handling

while I was studying Stanford CS 106 A I had to download acm.jar file. I have imported and everything worked fine till I wanted to run a simple program from the source code I got in video. The error down below:

[image]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcf9v.png)

When I want to run:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/evrhY.jpg

and the source code:

```
import acm.program.*;


    public class Add2Doubles extends ConsoleProgram {
        public void run() {
           println("This program adds two numbers.");
           int n1 = readInt("Enter n1: ");
           int n2 = readInt("Enter n2: ");
           int total = n1 + n2;
           println("The total is " + total + ".");
        }
     }
```

Thanks in advance for your helps. I'm on lecture 5.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Note that most people won't follow links, especially if they are to YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

Your javafile is not in your sources directory and hence not on your build-path.

Try moving `Add2Doubles.java` to your `src` folder.

edit: Thanks to the comment I thought about another suggestion: You might have to move your `acm` directory to the `src` folder as well (as indeed, that is where eclipse will look for your source files).

Comment: "on your build path" is Eclipse slang for where it looks for sources to compile.

Comment: Thank you guys. As already mentioned I moved the source code and acm folder into src folder now it works.

Answer (score 0):

The error explains it well enough to me? You've not got any sources! I believe that `URLClassLoader` is part of the default java runtime libraries so you can need to get the sources from the Java website.

Comment: Try doing what ljgw did then, also does it run correctly if you right click the java file and run it from there? Run As > Application